# ASP.Net OnGet - URL encoded Parameters - Only some parameters are Decoded by ASP.Net Framework

Tags: asp.net-core

Ola,
for some reason, it looks like ASP.Net Core Webserver (.Net 6) seems to url-decode some characters for the PageModel.OnGet Method and some characters are not url-decoded.

The request according URL in Internet Edge in the addressbar:

`http://localhost:5000/ItemsOverview/Data/dm%3A%2F%2F%2Fxxx.ebs.data%3Fmetaclass%3Ddm%253A%252F%252F%252Fxxx.ebs%25232d73a22b-8505-4523-939d-7f524253f95b`

This is what is sent to the OnGet Method:

`ItemsOverview.cshtml: @page "/ItemsOverview/{workspace}/{extent}/{item?}"`

```
ItemsOverview.cshtml.cs: 
public void OnGet(string workspace, string extent, string? item)
{
           Workspace = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(workspace);
           Extent = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(extent);
           Item = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(item);
}
```

The variable 'extent' as received by the debugger looks like the following:

dm:%2F%2F%2Fxxx.ebs.data?metaclass=dm%3A%2F%2F%2Fxxx.ebs%232d73a22b-8505-4523-939d-7f524253f95b

==> So, the server has changed %3F to '=' and %25 to '%', but not characters like %2F...

The url is generated by using the javascript function 'encodeURIComponent':

```
export function getLinkForNavigateToExtentItems(workspace: string, extentUri: string, parameter?: NavigationToExtentItemsParameter) {
    let urlParameter = "";
    let ampersand = '?';

    if (parameter?.metaClass !== undefined) {
        urlParameter += ampersand + "metaclass=" + encodeURIComponent(parameter.metaClass);
        ampersand = '&';
    }

    return Settings.baseUrl + "ItemsOverview/" +
        encodeURIComponent(workspace) + "/" +
        encodeURIComponent(extentUri + urlParameter);
}
```

**Expectation:**

The OnGet Call is called with the parameter 'extent' is given in the Url by Browser.

**Situation:**

Some characters are already decoded by Browser(?) or ASP.Net Core Framework(?)

Comment: Just installed Fiddler:

The GET Request is: 

> GET /ItemsOverview/Data/dm%3A%2F%2F%2Fxxx.ebs.data%3Fmetaclass%3Ddm%253A%252F%252F%252Fxxx.ebs%25232d73a22b-8505-4523-939d-7f524253f95b HTTP/1.1

(no unwanted decoding by the browser)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23633 <- There seems to be a connection...

Comment: In old .net versions,it would convert "2f%" to "/" automaticlly,but not it won't to avoid the wrong path

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by:

```
  public static string? DecodePath(string? pathToBeDecoded)
   {
       return pathToBeDecoded?
                .Replace("%2F", "/")
                .Replace("%2f", "/")
                .Replace("%25", "#");;
   }
```

I'm not convinced, but it seems to work.